# Custom cell values and drop-down menus

Tags: drop-down-menu, libreoffice, calc

Just recently workplace changed it's decades old "write your daily reports on piece of paper" to very early stage of digital version of that, but, as it most of the time goes in rather big companies - things get implemented slowly. So, just to ease calculations and daily reports, decided to do my own version of their overly complicated sistem, which includes simple formulas like =sum(A1*A2) which would generate a simple report with "actions I've made * cost of action = $

Everything is simple enough, but there are several actions which get paid differently if done by more than one person or size of detail is different (Everything is related to physical actions, basically)

So, I got the idea how to create drop-down menu in which I can add cell values to take, but I was wondering if it's possible to create a cell that visually says, let's say "3 people's work" or "detail is bigger than 1,5m3" and under those hides different numeric values?

[These are the rows I'd like to change to drop-down, which has values seperated by dashes, making them not just numeric values, but with explanatory one-line text to them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F055E.png)

Would really appreciate some help on this. My previous skills on Calc or office software in general is somewhat very basic and primitive.  Thanks in advance for any tips and tricks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! The "simple formula" that you gave as an example does not make sense - the [**SUM() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060106.html?&DbPAR=WRITER&System=WIN#Section16) with one argument will return the same result as formula `=A1*A2`. You can learn about the text and numerical values of the drop-down lists from many videos on YouTube, for example [**from this one**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VYxfTiODlo).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, probably I can't explain what I want to get as a result, but I will check that out!